# Next js api call

Tags: next.js

I'm working with NextJS 13.4.

Inside the app folder, I've made an API folder. I added a new folder called proxy inside the api folder and included route.js inside that proxy folder. I retrieved it as fetch('api/proxy') when I was on the home page, so the request looked like this: http://localhost:3000/api/proxy and it was successful. I then navigated to another page called About and called my API there with the command fetch('api/proxy'). At this time, it is not responding to requests made at http://localhost:3000/about/api/proxy.

The key issue for me is that any page—about, home, or contact—from which I want to call that API should be able to do so. I want any page, not just this one, to be able to call the API.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: Please don't make someone else fix all your capitalization issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `fetch('/api/proxy')`; you're missing the leading slash.

Comment: Thanks, I am really dumb I tried it two hours ago and now I remembered why it was not working bcz after editing the file I didn't press fkin ctrl+s. i think i need rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch in full url should solve your issue: `http://localhost:3000/api/proxy`

Comment: yep! It worked that way!